# Async method not running in parallel

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

In the following code, in the B method, the code Trace.TraceInformation("B - Started"); never gets called.

Should the method be running in parallel?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static async Task A()
        {
            for (;;)
            {
            }
        }


        private static async Task B()
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("B - Started");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task> { A(), B() };
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is a quality of a busy wait. Does A() peg the CPU at 100%?

Comment: I have 4 processors. One is 100%. Still, should then be running in concurrent (parallel)?

Comment: @FernandoSilva see  `Task.Run`. Only adding `async` doesn't make them parallel.

Comment: @FernandoSilva: This code will cause compiler warnings. Please read them; they explain exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Short answer**

No, as you wrote your two `async` methods, they are indeed not running in parallel. Adding `await Task.Yield();` to your first method (e.g. inside the loop) *would* allow them to do so, but there are more reasonable and straightforward methods, highly depending on what you actually need (interleaved execution on a single thread? Actual parallel execution on multiple threads?).

**Long answer**

First of all, declaring functions as `async` does not inherently make them run asynchronously or something. It rather simplifies the syntax to do so - read more about the concepts here: [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)

Effectively `A` is not asynchronous at all, as there is not a single `await` inside its method body. Instructions up to the first use of `await` run synchronously like a regular method would.

From then on, the object that you `await` determines what happens next, i.e. the context that the remaining method runs in.

To **force** execution of a task to happen on another thread, use `Task.Run` or similar.

In this scenario, adding `await Task.Yield()` does the trick since the current synchronization context is `null` and this happens to indeed cause the task scheduler (should be `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`) to execute the remaining instuctions on a thread-pool thread - some environment or configuration might cause you to only have one of them, so things would still not run in parallel.

**Summary**

The moral of the story is: Be aware of the differences between two concepts:

- concurrency (which is enabled by using `async`/`await` reasonably) and
- parallelism (which only happens when concurrent tasks get *scheduled* the right way **or** if you enforce it using `Task.Run`, `Thread`, etc. in which case the use of `async` is completely irrelevant anyway)

Answer (score 2):

The `async` modifier is not a magic spawn-a-thread-here marker. It's sole purpose is to let the compiler know a method *might* depend on some asynchronous operation (A complex data-processing thread, I/O...) so it has to setup a state machine to coordinate the callbacks resulting from those asynchronous operations.

To make `A` run on another thread you would invoke it using [Task.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx) which wraps the invocation on a new thread with a Task object, which you can await. Be aware that `await`-ing a method does not mean your code runs in parallel to `A`'s execution all by itself: It will until the very line you `await` the Task object, telling the compiler you **need** the value that the Task object returns. In this case `await`-ing `Task.Run(A)` will effectively make your program run forever, waiting for `A` to return, something that will never happen (barring computer malfunction).

Do have in mind that marking a method as async but not actually awaiting anything will only have the effect of a compiler warning. If you await something that is not truly async (It returns immediately on the calling thread with something like [Task.FromResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922(v=vs.110).aspx)) it will mean your program takes a runtime speed penalty. It is very slight, however.

Answer (score 1):

No, the methods shown are not expected to "run in parallel".

Why `B` is never called - you have list of tasks `tasks` constructed via essentially series of `.Add` calls - and first is *result* of `A()` is added. Since the `A` method does not have any `await` it will run to the completion synchronously on the same thread. And after that `B()` would be called.

Now `A` will never complete (it is sitting in infinite loop) so really code will not even reach call to `B`.

Note that even if creation would succeed code never finish `WaitAll` as `A` still sits in infinite loop.

If you want methods to "run in parallel" you need to either run them implicitly/explicitly on new threads (i.e. with `Task.Run` or `Thread.Start`) or for I/O bound calls let method to release thread with `await`.

Comment: This is true but it is a very incomplete answer.

Comment: You shouldn't delete it, it adds very important information on it's current form.